# Too many positional options error, Mongodb - mongoexport?

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I cannot figure out why im producing this error when trying to do a simple export of 3 fields to a .csv file for mongodb.  My code is as follows:

```
c:mongodb24\bin>mongoexport -db local -c pets -f type,name, color --csv -o c:\Data\CSC 451\spreadsheet.csv
```

Error: too many positional options

I'm wanting to export the type, name, and color data into the spreadsheet csv file.

Comment: Is that space necessary between name and color?

Comment: I found the error but I believe it was due to my file path for the exported csv.  I had a space in the folder name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer:

c:mongodb24\bin>mongoexport -db local -c pets -f type,name,color --csv -o c:\Data\CSC451\spreadsheet.csv

Comment: You're own answer does not provide enough value due to lack of explanation. Please go into detail, what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this.

1.) remove the space inthe filepath

```
c:mongodb24\bin>mongoexport -db local -c pets -f type,name,color --csv -o c:\Data\CSC451\spreadsheet.csv
```

2.)surround the filepath in quotes

```
c:mongodb24\bin>mongoexport -db local -c pets -f type,name,color --csv -o "c:\Data\CSC 451\spreadsheet.csv"
```

Windows doesn't like Space's in the file path so you either have to remove the space, or if you can't do that without affecting something else you need to wrap it in double quotes.

EDIT: Windows requires the query to be surrounded in double quotes while strings are surrounded in single quotes. In Linux the inverse is true, strings in double quotes and the query in single.